# Erro ao popular array, firebase, galeria de fotos ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, array, android-studio, galeria, adapter

já estou há três dias pesquisando sobre esse erro e não consigo consertá-lo. Estou montando uma galeria de fotos para meu app e preciso popular uma Array com as fotos vindas do Firebase para assim mostrá-las na galeria. Esse erro ocorre ao clicar na galeria, pelo que já pesquisei o erro acontece quando coloco itens no array e o seu tamanho muda, eu teria que notificar o Adapter utilizando o notifyDataSetChanged(), porém não consegui uma maneira de fazer isso ou estou notificando no lugar errado, já utilizei esse método em vários lugares e nada... Alguém poderia me ajudar?
ABaixo o código

```
public class Galeria extends AppCompatActivity {

private GaleriaImagensAdapter adapter;
private List<String> valores;
private List<String> temporaria;
private ViewPager galeria;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_galeria);

    getIntentAtual();

    galeria = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_galeria);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(valores == null){
        valores = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    valores = ConfiguracaoFirebase.galeriaFire();

    if (adapter == null){
        adapter = new GaleriaImagensAdapter(this, valores);
        galeria.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

private void getIntentAtual(){

    if(getIntent().hasExtra("nome_sessao") && getIntent().hasExtra("sessao_bd")){
        String tituloSessao = getIntent().getStringExtra("nome_sessao");
        String nomeSessaoBD = getIntent().getStringExtra("sessao_bd");

    }else{
        Log.i("falha", "sem nada");
    }
}
}
```

Aqui o Adapter da galeria

```
public class GaleriaImagensAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> valores;
private boolean doNotifyDataSetChangedOnce = false;
private int[] imagens = new int[] { R.drawable.cadastrar_usuario_branco_extraido, R.drawable.cadastrar_usuario_branco, R.drawable.cadastrar_usuario};

public GaleriaImagensAdapter(Context contextm, List<String> valor){

        this.valores = valor;

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    if (doNotifyDataSetChangedOnce){

        doNotifyDataSetChangedOnce = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    return valores.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup pager, int position, Object object){
    ((ViewPager) pager).removeView((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup pager, int position){


    ImageView imagem = new ImageView(context);
    imagem.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    Glide.with(context).load(valores.get(position)).into(imagem);
    ((ViewPager) pager).addView(imagem, 0);
    return imagem;
}
}
```

Aqui o código do firebase:

```
 public static List galeriaFire(){

    final List<String> imagensGaleria = new ArrayList<>();

    firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("sessoes").child("galeria").child("2018").child("agosto");

    post = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                imagensGaleria.add(child.getValue().toString());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    firebase.addValueEventListener(post);
    return imagensGaleria;

}
```

Abaixo o erro:

```
  09-14 12:36:06.651 3166-3166/doeamor.acaosocial.com.doeamor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: doeamor.acaosocial.com.doeamor, PID: 3166
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 3 Pager id: doeamor.acaosocial.com.doeamor:id/vp_galeria Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class doeamor.acaosocial.com.doeamor.Adapter.GaleriaImagensAdapter
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1137)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1212)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1552)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```